# httpclient class is not working in android

Tags: android, database, httpclient

I am working on an Android project, in that i need to send the login details to an online database.I done my code as below...
But when i run my project only the else condition is working.
nothing is passing to database

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    EditText un,pw,vn;
    Button ok,reg;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        un=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.u_name);
        pw=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwd);
        vn=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.vh_number);
        ok=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
       reg=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnregister);

        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", un.getText().toString()));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pw.getText().toString()));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vehiclenumber", vn.getText().toString()));
                //String valid = "1";
                String response = null;
                try {

                        response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://192.168.1.23/test_login/check.php", postParameters);
                    Log.d("sarath","");
                    String res=response.toString();
                   // res = res.trim();
                    res= res.replaceAll("\\s+","");                              
                    //error.setText(res);

                   if(res.equals("1"))
                   {                                      
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);

                   }            
                    else
                    {

                        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                        CharSequence message = "The Username or Password you entered is incorrect.!";
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, duration);       
                        toast.show();
                    }


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    un.setText(e.toString());
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly is in `res` string?

Comment: Or more importantly - what is CustomHttpClient doing? Can you post the source please?

Comment: it is the responsestring that coming from the php output while checking the username and password in the db

Comment: where should i post  this code

Comment: @goku edit your post with CustomHttpClient class. For additional help for [how to use httppost](http://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2012/01/27/handling-http-post-method-in-android/) click on the hyperlink

Comment: I put it here www.idone.com/JrudQ

Comment: I would advice to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and also not to state that "X does not work"... put it the other way "Problem 'xxx' with X" or "X returns xxx".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code.

```
DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
                ResponseHandler<String> res = new BasicResponseHandler(); 
                HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(
                           "http://192.168.1.23/test_login/check.php");
                 ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                 postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", un.getText().toString()));
                 postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pw.getText().toString()));
                 postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vehiclenumber", vn.getText().toString()));
               try {

                 postMethod
                     .setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                               postParameters ));

               String response = hc.execute( postMethod,res);
               if(response.equals("1"))
               {                                      
                   Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
               }            
               else
                  {             
                   Context context = getApplicationContext();
                   CharSequence message = "The Username or Password you entered is incorrect.!";
                   int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                   Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, duration);       
                     toast.show();
                }

            }
                 catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
```

Comment: can u explain me what is hc and res ?

Comment: hc is object of DefaultHttpClient to use Creates a new HTTP client from parameters and a connection manager.and res is the object of ResponseHandler that returns the response body as a String for successful  responses.

Comment: where is the catch statement?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code after adding perameters:

try {

```
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(" your url");



            ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters= new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();                    
             postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", un.getText().toString()));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pw.getText().toString()));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vehiclenumber", vn.getText().toString()));


             httpPost.setEntity ( new  UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));



            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            line = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
        }

        return line;

}
```

Comment: for this i have already created another custom http client class